# Followed adwice for err 1045 but new problems Have made Grant statement too

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

wamp local
Lost contact with all dbases except one which I can log in to. In that DB my password is on a databas level and not a grant user. I have checked all earlier answers. First I did get error 1045 and took the advice given to use "cookie" instead of config in phpmyadmin config.inc 
Logged in to phpmyadmin and got two other errors

1. needs a secret blowfish..??
2. Something wrong in config file. Doesn't say which and no more info

Fixed them(realy dont know how)
Have made The grant privileges statement for root.

Now I can come in with root user bud also every other user with or without password.
Then I can see my databases and tables(only titles)

I have checked that my DB files are still under the folders(msql bin data)
Got a message Before about something wrong in the config file. Checked it several times(config.inc.php) without seeing anything suspect.

Please... What to do?

Comment: About your item 2, what's the exact message displayed? I suspect there's more information there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your question is. It sounds like you worked through items 1 and 2. Sounds like you're logging in as root (as expected) and as the anonymous user (that's "every other user with or without password"). You can restrict that by removing the anonymous user (log in as root and click on the Users tab).